# Duplicate entries for Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Instead of adding new items into the existing list, I want to create a new list for the new items. For example,

`FINAL OUTPUT:[[case1, this is method A], [case2, this is method A]]`

However, my codes output was

`FINAL OUTPUT:[[case1, this is method A, case2, this is method A], [case1, this is method A, case2, this is method A]]`

I am not too sure where did I go wrong. 
Any help with be appreciated! Thanks!

Below are my codes.

```
   static List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int q = 1; q < 3; q++) {
            switch (q) {
            case 1:
                temp.add("case1");
                methodA();
                list.add(temp);
                break;

            case 2:
                temp.add("case2");
                methodA();
                list.add(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FINAL OUTPUT:" + list);
    }

    private static void methodA() {
        temp.add("this is method A");
    }
```

Comment: `temp` should ideally be declared inside the loop. And sent to a `methodA(List<String> temp)`. The problem you have is a common consequence of using scopes that are broader than necessary.

Comment: The loop is absolutely pointless in this form, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence

Comment: @Clashsoft, no, it's not. OP wants to enter the `switch` 2 times

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko The loop and switch are pointless, see the link. The first time the switch is entered q is 1, the second time 2. He could remove the loop head, the switch, the case labels and the break statements and the code would be doing the same thing as before, and would be easier to understand.

Comment: @Clashsoft, what **if** the OP want to _test_ the all possible (and acceptable) cases with this snippet? (If it isn't the purpose of this code, you're absolutely right).

Comment: @zlakad Possible but in this question I think the problem is not related to loops or switches, but to the fact that `temp` is added to `list` as a reference and subsequent modification of `temp` modifies all elements of `list`, thus the "duplicate entries"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to clear the temp-list with each loop or re-instatiate it. I personally prefer option 2.

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();   

public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int q = 1; q < 3; q++) {

            temp = new ArrayList<>();

            switch (q) {
            case 1:
                temp.add("case1");
                methodA();
                list.add(temp);
                break;

            case 2:
                temp.add("case2");
                methodA();
                list.add(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `clear()` affects a list that already added to the final result (at the previous iteration), you have to make a copy (1) before clearing it (2).

```
list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));  // 1
temp.clear();                     // 2
```

Let's move 3 duplicate lines out of the `switch`.

```
switch (q) {
    case 1:
        temp.add("case1");
        break;

    case 2:
        temp.add("case2");
        break;
}
methodA();
list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
temp.clear();
```

Answer (score -2):

This is happening because you are adding complete Arraylist into the list of strings without clearing it.
What you can do is inside every case statement clear the arrayList temp

```
for (int q = 1; q < 3; q++) {
        switch (q) {
        case 1:
            temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add("case1");
            methodA();
            list.add(temp);
            break;

        case 2:
            temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add("case2");
            methodA();
            list.add(temp);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you would end up with a list with elements which refer to the same object

Comment: @AndrewTobilko got it correct, commented wrong line.